# Jira RPC/SOAP GetCustomFields()

Tags: c#, soap, jira

I know that CustomFields() can get only administrator or I can used getFieldsForEdit (if I know issue key).  But most of user doesn't have this permission or doesn't know issue key.
Does another way for it?
I used Jira SOAP interface within a C#.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using the REST API if you are using JIRA 5.0 or later